# Could not find a file on the SonarQube server

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, build-definition

I have created a Buid definition with sonar qube, when i queue this definition am getting this error

2019-10-17T06:50:18.8597382Z ##----[error]Could not find a file on the SonarQube server. Url: http://my_url/static/csharp/SonarQube.MSBuild.Runner.Implementation.zip

2019-10-17T06:50:18.8597382Z ##-----[error]Failed to update the SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild binaries. Check the server url, verify that the C# plugin is correctly installed on the SonarQube server and that the SonarQube server has been restarted.

2019-10-17T06:50:18.8597382Z ##----[error]Pre-processing failed. Exit code: 1

2019-10-17T06:50:18.8753532Z ##----[error]System.Exception: Unexpected exit code received from batch file: 1

i have C#(version 6) plugin
sonarQube Version 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just downgrade your csharp(C#) version to 5.11